# facebook redirect behaviour when getting back from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook

I am currently working on iframe facebook application http://apps.facebook.com/rubycastle/

It is RoR application with REST controllers. 
When I use the redirect_to path I see "go to Facebook" message with their logo within my iframe.

How to get rid of it? Anyone knows?

You can see it when going to "Barracks" then clicking links:
Send new warrior to training
Get ready warriors

No worry with testing, I do get only facebook_id saved to the database, and for the time being I'm removing all users to work on a clean set. No data will be saved afterwards.

Comment: sorry for the broken link before. Seems like http://apps.facebook.com/rubycastle/ is the only valid entry for the app for now. Have to fix that as well ^^"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason is because the [new warrior link](http://78.47.31.83/warriors/new) first redirects back to your Facebook app's [barracks page](http://apps.facebook.com/rubycastle/barracks) (which is displaying the logo you mention), which then in turn does a post to your servers [barracks page](http://78.47.31.83/barracks).  You should have the new link return the content you want, or have it redirect directly to your servers barracks page, without loading the Facebook page in the middle.

Comment: I think it may be connected to the REST behaviour. When you create object with 'new' controller method you usually point form to the create action which will usually redirect to the index. Maybe it is wrong pattern when developing for facebook. I will give it a try.

Comment: Yes, it is the correct answer. When I know how it works, then I can deal with it. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, the best solution to this was to render portion of javascript that did redirect an iframe to the site I needed. It was acceptable and works really fine.